# How to make text into a hyperlink in a UILabel or UITextField

Tags: ios, hyperlink, uiwebview, uitextfield, uilabel

I'd like to make a UILabel or UIText file contain text the works like an address field in html, not the site itself. I.e. it would look like

"Click here to view **My Web Site** etc. etc. etc."

where "My Web Site" is text which when clicked will take you to  "http://myWebSite.com".

I've checked around, but it's not clear I can show the text instead of the hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Use [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) library for clickable labels, supports iOS version >=4.3.